# How to use a group by or having clause instead of inner join MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this query

```
SELECT K.ID, K.`TYPE`, K1.`TYPE`,
FROM table K
INNER JOIN table K1
ON K1.ID = K.ID
WHERE K1.`TYPE` = 'ISSN'
AND K.`TYPE` = 'ISBN'
```

It looks for one object ID having two records, one with type = ISSN and one with ISBN.

These tables are very big and this query takes about ten minutes to run. Is there a faster alternative to using either nested select (on the same table) or group by having syntax

Thank you

Comment: I see only one table named, `table`

Comment: Yes there is only one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` version:

```
SELECT K.ID
FROM table K
WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN')
GROUP BY K.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT K.`TYPE`) = 2
```

If an ID can have only distinct type values, you can do `HAVING COUNT(K.`TYPE`) = 2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely give you improved performance over `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
SELECT K.ID
FROM table K
WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN')
GROUP BY K.ID
HAVING min(K.`TYPE`) <> max(K.`TYPE`)
```